# How can I access a CHAR_INFO structure from within a function

Tags: c, windows, winapi, console

I have some very basic code that is using the Windows API to display random characters and colours to the console by accessing the console buffer directly.

My problem is that I want to put the nested for loop into a separate function outside the `main()` function. Ideally this function would take the struct `consoleBuffer` as an argument/parameter but I dont know how the sintax for a CHAR_INFO struct works well enough. The other option is declaring `consoleBuffer` as a global outside the main function so that it can be accesed anywhere and we dont have to set it as a parameter but this does not work.

code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define WIDTH 70
#define HEIGHT 35

HANDLE wHnd; //Write Handle

int main(void)
{
 int x, y;
  
 SMALL_RECT windowSize = {0, 0, WIDTH - 2, HEIGHT - 2};

 // screen buffer size
 COORD bufferSize = {WIDTH, HEIGHT};
  
 // Variables for WriteConsoleOutput
 COORD characterBufferSize = {WIDTH, HEIGHT};
 COORD characterPosition = {0, 0};
 SMALL_RECT consoleWriteArea = {0, 0, WIDTH - 1, HEIGHT - 1};
  
 // A CHAR_INFO structure containing data about a single character
 CHAR_INFO consoleBuffer[WIDTH * HEIGHT];
 
 wHnd = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
 
 // Console title
 SetConsoleTitle("CONSOLE");
 
 //Set window
 SetConsoleWindowInfo(wHnd, TRUE, &windowSize);

 //Buffer size
 SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(wHnd, bufferSize);
  
 while(1){
  for (y = 0; y < HEIGHT; ++y){
   for (x = 0; x < WIDTH; ++x){
    consoleBuffer[x + WIDTH * y].Char.AsciiChar = 'a';
    consoleBuffer[x + WIDTH * y].Attributes = rand() % 256;
   }
  }
  
  //Write characters
  WriteConsoleOutputA(wHnd, consoleBuffer, characterBufferSize, characterPosition, &consoleWriteArea);
 }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you confused about? Creating a function declaration/definition, passing in parameters, types of parameters? This should be clarified in your question.

Comment: It is not clear what your issue actually is. Please clarify. What kind of parameters do you WANT `draw_Chars()` to take in? Please show an example of what you are struggling with.

Comment: @SafelyFast Simplified the question in the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially the problem is that you need to set pointer to the `CHAR_INFO` struct if you want it as an argument. An example of the funcion could be the following:

```
void foo(CHAR_INFO* cB) {
    int x,y;
    for (y = 0; y < HEIGHT; ++y) {
        for (x = 0; x < WIDTH; ++x) {
            cB[x + WIDTH * y].Char.AsciiChar = 'a';
            cB[x + WIDTH * y].Attributes = rand() % 256;
        }
    }
}
```